# "Long overdue" in Italian

Tags: english-comparison, translation

How does one say that something is **long overdue** in Italian?

For instance, is it correct to say something like "Fa molto tempo che sia in attesa"?

Comment: consider also the colloquial form "scaduto da un pezzo".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the context.

If it's past the deadline / expected date:

> (Qualcosa) è (ben) oltre la scadenza prevista.

If it's something that has been promised long time ago:

> È da (tanto) tempo che lo/la si aspetta.

If it's something that should have been done before something else or just long time ago:

> (Qualcosa) avrebbe dovuto essere fatto prima / avrebbe dovuto essere fatto (tanto) tempo fa.

*Essere in attesa*, as you've suggested, has connotation of "being pregnant, being expecting a child." If that's the context, then one could simply say *ritardo della nascita* or *la nascita si fa attendere*.

Comment: I'd use "(qualcosa) è **ben** oltre la scadenza prevista". Otherwise it is just overdue :-) Same for the third example.

Comment: Right. Thanks, @mau. I've edited the answer. :)

Comment: Also a passive form for the second case: “A lungo atteso/a”

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what I.M. already put in his answer I wanted to add that a generic overdue time is often called "ritardo".

This is valid in many cases:

"The job was completed past its due time" = "il lavoro è stato finito in ritardo"

"She arrived late" = "(Lei) è arrivata in ritardo"

and many other cases generically referring to something that was expected earlier than when it eventually happened, including childbirth, menstruation, intellectual development of a child, traveling, somebody slow in understanding a joke, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest translation to **long overdue** is
**scaduto da molto (tempo)**. Example:

> La bolletta e` scaduta. ( the bill's long overdue )
>
> Da domani i Buoni Postali saranno scaduti. ( the bonds will be expired, by tomorrow )
>
> Questo cibo e` scaduto. ( this food is past its sell-by date )

Answer (score 1):

"E' da un sacco di tempo che stiamo aspettando."

It can be written as:

"E' da un sacco che stiamo aspettando"

Answer (score 1):

I think you wish to keep the -due- component, where it has some duty related force. Indeed *due* is derived form latin  *debeo, debēre, debui, debitus* which I understand can be translated by *to owe, ought* (you owe debt to the govt)

A almost literal translation is indeed possible

il riconoscimento a **lungo dovuto** finalmente è giunto
la risposta che ha *lungo* ti **dovevo** oggi ti invio

(la seconda suona forse un poco ricercata)